# how I view the enum value of a watch expression instead of the real value in eclipse debugger C/C++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, enums, watch

I am using eclipse debugger , I added some variables to the watch to check how they change through the code , the problem is I want to see these variables as the enum values I gave to them in the code and not the int value ? thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

so let's say you have

```
enum myEnum {
    TheFirst=0, TheSecond=10
};
```

and now you want to see the name instead of the value (eg. TheFirst instead of 0)?
I don't think that's possible because in c++ enums are resolved at compile-time which means the "names" are non-existent at runtime. That makes it indistinguishable from a normal int.

**related Question on SO:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9150550/3611557

Comment: yes this is exactly what i want , but I am coding C not C++... the only reason i wrote c++ is because I think its sthg about the editor and not the compiler . thanks anyway